# Sizing protection diodes

Tags: diodes, circuit-protection, tvs, reverse-polarity

In designing basic upfront protection in a circuit, I've encountered a strange conundrum.  I find it's very difficult to size both a reverse voltage protection diode, and a transient voltage diode (TVS) at the same time.

Some background:

I designed a basic circuit with a switching regulator.  The circuit has a buffer capacitor up front of 470uF, as well as a reverse voltage diode (we've had problems with hooking things up backwards in the past) and a TVS diode.  The setup looks as follows (pink blob is stuff that needs protecting):

[image: Basic protection layout]

The curiosities commence.  The forward surge to fill the capacitor is quite large (the resistance of the capacitor is rated for 60mOhm), resulting in an unpleasant surge of up to 200A!  That's a lot!  I added the capacitor just as an afterthought, not knowing / thinking about inrush consequences, and it resulted in D1 being destroyed at turn-on.  The temporary fix was to remove the diode/replace it with a short and just not hook things up backwards, but for a long term solution I have to look into (and learn about) two things:

1. 1 time forward surge ratings.
2. Choosing appropriate capacitance/ESR ratings to accommodate (1).  Selecting LARGE ESR ratings, (or adding in series resistance if needed).

Now that's all fine and dandy.  I understand how to do this / where I went wrong.  What doesn't gel so well is the case of protecting the circuit in the event of a TVS.  It is my understanding that the TVS will flip on and bypass current (a lot of it) when an overvoltage event occurs.  Am I not bound to the same limitations of the forward surge ratings of D1 in this scenario?  e.g. how do you not blow up D1 when D2 is surging large voltages at high amperages for very short periods of time?  I see a few options:

1. Add series resistance to D2.

Questions:

a. How does this affect it's ability to protect the circuit?
b. Don't the in-line resistors have to be huge to handle the incoming current spike?  This is a theme here.  It seems like everything in the path (current loop) of the TVS when activated by a spike needs to be HUGE and rated for appropiate wattages which in the case of resistors is outstandingly massive.

2. Assume D1 won't blow up because a TVS event doesn't last 8.3 ms.

Questions:

a. 8.3 ms is the duration of the rating.  What's the rule of thumb?  Do I do a "power equivalency" calculation/rating e.g. I_surge * time == I_TVS_Surge * T_tvs_event?  Obviously that will not hold up at some point if at all.

I'm definitely missing something here, but the question is bugging me.  Every diagram of TVS/Reverse diode protection I've seen doesn't have massive resistor bundles attached (or I'm not looking at the right diagrams).

Thanks
Matt

edit:
Just to throw some numbers in here:
I'm powering off 12v, with solar charging (could feasibly get up to 16/18).  Rest of circuit is designed to take a max input of 36V.  Protection diode has a working voltage of 18, clamp @29.

Now I think I've overkilled with diode selection etc, but I need this thing reliable.  The TVS is rated for 5kW, and the reverse protection has a forward surge rating of 600A (and it's absolutely MASSIVE).  Needing through-hole parts probably isn't helping, right? (It's just for a prototype right now).

tvs:http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/littelfuse-inc/5KP18A/5KP18ALFCT-ND/1530615

reverse_polarity: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/microsemi-corporation/APT75DQ60BG/APT75DQ60BG-ND/1494833

So, going with the calculations, if D2 starts conducting, it's

I = V/R ->

I_surge = (V_Surge - V_drop_D1 - V_clamp_D2) / (R_power_line + R_diodes + R_optional_series_resistors).

I'm not entirely sure how to calculate the amperage going through it as V_surge is just a function, and R_diodes is probably a function of V_surge.  Maybe could back that out of the data sheets?

I also have a few 50mOhm resistors to throw in series, but they're only rated to 5W (and they're already huge!) and I'm suspect to think that they would just get blown up if I put them in.

resistors: https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=mpr5jb50l0

Comment: *resulting in an unpleasant surge of up to 200A* That is, assuming the 12 V source can deliver that current. Can it ? Are you just **simulating** this or building it ? Not clear what you're doing. If you want the TVS protection to actually **work** then you have to **interrupt the current during over voltage**. Now you're trying to make the TVS absorb all the overvoltage power. That will not work. Replace D1 with a **fuse**. Then place D1 **in parallel** with D2 such that D1 conducts when the polartity is reversed. Then reversed polarity will **blow the fuse** and protect the circuit.

Comment: Also have a look how to use a TVS here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/259278/tvs-diode-for-surge-protection-how-does-it-works-beyond-ipp-point/259282#259282 and about reverse voltage protection here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/284214/design-of-a-single-cell-low-voltage-reverse-battery-protection-circuit/284222#284222

Comment: Current source is a car battery.  I'm prone to believe the "cold cranking 225 amps" advertisement on the label?

Comment: It is not clear what are you protecting from what. To begin, use of TVS in parallel with huge capacitor makes no sense.

Comment: OK, indeed a a car battery can deliver that amount of current. The inrush current is generally not a problem, you also neglected the series resistance of D1 and wiring resistance. Also you don't need to have D1 if you do the rev. protection as I suggested. The fuse will not blow as C1 charges, fuses are too slow for that. Also I do not see why you would **need** the TVS as the circuit which needs protection can handle 36 V. A car battery will explode before reaching 36 V. I think you only need the reverse protection, which can be done with a **fuse** and a **diode**.

Comment: @ali I'm protecting against 2 things.  1.  Reverse voltage.  I'l use mustache's reccomendation of inline fuse.  2.  Transient voltage spikes (not the battery going into "crazy mode" but rather spikes in the line on connect/disconnect.  We blew out parts while hooking up the power lines that were rated to 36V so it's my assumption that there was a spike in the line (hence trying to put a tvs diode in front to clamp those).

Comment: @ali continued...  I now understand that maybe it's imprudent to try and protect against large spikes (where would they come from? if lightning comes down and smites my box, well, then so be it, right?)  If the power lines were very long and went out to some station down the line, then it makes sense, but when everything is in an enclosed container, it seems much less likely.  However, some protection is prudent, right?

Comment: @mustache,  I'll add in the relative resistances to my final calculation.  It was more a general question of where my understanding was going amiss.  So it's my understanding that the TVS essentially clamps everything DOWNSTREAM, then you're left with the current loop of the tvs to handle the wattage (which a couple watt-rated resistor of a reasonable value [say a few kohm?]), as opposed to just letting the tvs handle the wattage itself.  That current loop will be driven by the excess voltage of the surge, so you size to that.  Seem about right?

Comment: @ali again.  Are tvs diodes not a valid source of protection against esd?  The electronics will be in a plastic enclosure outdoors, where people will be servicing them regularly.  I would think we need esd protection (so why not a tvs diode?).  Surely a capacitor alone does not suffice.

Comment: TVS are used  where you can't use a sizable capacitor, like on high-speed low-voltage signal pins, like USB pins. The capacitor alone is already a perfect short to absorb ESD event (unless it has very long leads and/or has bad internal inductance. But in this case you just add few 0.1uF SMT ceramic caps in parallel. If you have big ringing on connect, you need to add common-mode chokes or other filters, look how it is done in other devices like PSU for PCs.

Comment: @FakeMoustache, the way of reverse protection you're describing has the fuse blow when connected in reverse, but you can also do it the diode way bathMarm0t already has outlined and then you don't need to worry about replacing the fuse (but it does have a diode drop all the time).

Comment: @mbrig You're telling me nothing I don't know already but OP assumed that a very large current was flowing when C1 charges so he had a problem with the diode. Anyway, it is a confusing story as the large inrush current doesn't actually happen anyway.

Comment: @bathMarm0t If you design it such that the TVS will absorb all the excess power, you can forget about protecting against high power (like lightning strike) because the **TVS cannot handle that** you'd need a TVS the size of toaster. Yes, that sounds silly. So **interrupting** the power is what needs to be done. Either with a fuse or other means.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of inrush currents into massive capacitive loads has been solved in industry by use of thermistor elements (negative or positive temperature coefficient thermistors), see "[PTC Thermistors For Inrush Current Limiting](https://www.ametherm.com/inrush-current/ptc-thermistors-for-inrush-current-limiting)" Without them every PC would blow household breaker circuits every time you plug a PC into AC outlet.

Surge protection will be also improved/solved after installing NTC or PTC inrush limiters.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally normal to have some inductance in the DC feed. Seeing several coils is quite common             .This is for EMC reasons .If it is a buck converter it would be to attenuate ripple so it does not radiate along the cable .If it is say a car radio the inductance would be there to stop ignition and alternator noise getting into the audio.If the inductor is present like it should be then its DCR may be enough to limit turn on surge current .Remember that the characteristic impedance also limits surge current.In other words you can manipulate the existing L and C and get turn on     surge currents much lower than would be implied by the battery volts and the circuit DCR .This inductance    makes D2 do less work and reduces the size of D1 .